# Stick commands does not register

Tags: inav

I'm trying to follow [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwoDb7WF6c8nj7G3o9NJpzVPPTsw2z-Jy) to set up a drone with iNav, but when it comes to calibrating the compass, the stick command doesn't seem to work (the status light on the FC doesn't flash rapidly as described in the video). When trying some other stick commands it doesn't seem to register either.

All the endpoint are set to min 1000 and max 2000. Min_check and max_check are 1100 and 1900 respectively.

The FC is a Matek f405 std, and the radio is a Taranis qx7s, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out rather quickly when I tried to arm the quad and it said that the throttle was not low. It turned out that throttle and pitch was switched in iNav....

So after changing that, everything worked...